# Problem when serializing objects with strings that contain "/"

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datacontractjsonserializer

I am using `DataContractJsonSerializer` to serialize an object, and to do this I am using the following function:

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T obj)
{
    string returnVal = "";
    try
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
            returnVal = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception /*exception*/)
    {
        returnVal = "";
         //log error
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

Now, this function is **working well and great**...except in the following situation (I am dubitative if to change it, since I don't know how it will affect the rest of my code).

**The situation in which it does not work well**

Say I have **obj** (the argument) an object such as:

```
[DataContract()]
public class theObject
{
   [DataMember()]
   public string image;
}
```

in which `image` holds the Base64 value of a BMP file. 
It is a big value but for example it would start as:  `"Qk1W/QAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAAawAAAMgAAAABABgAAAAAACD9AADEDgAAxA4AAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////////////////////////////7+/...."`

So you see that it contains a lot of `/`s.

So when I pass this object to `Serialize` it will `WriteObject` in ms and then get this into an array that finally will go to `returnVal`.

Now let's examine `returnVal`. It is in JSON format (correct) and when you visualize it as JSON it will show you:

```
image:"Qk1W/QAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAAawAAAMgAAAABABgAAAAAACD9AADEDgAAxA4AAAAAAAAAAAAA////////////////////////////////////7+/...."
```

However! when you visualize it as text it will show you:

```
"image":"Qk1W\/QAAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAAawAAAMgAAAABABgAAAAAACD9AADEDgAAxA4AAAAAAAAAAAAA\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/7+\/..."
```

Did you see? it has inserted `\` before every `/` and it makes a lot of difference.

So my questions are:

1. Why visualizing it as JSON and visualizing it as Text shows different things?
2. How can I get after serialization the correct value (without the `/`s)

EDIT:

Although one can say that `\/` and `/` are the same, the consequences are not. Later when using this JSON to throw it to a Web Api using

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);                    
byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(content);
```

the version with added `\` results in a `bytes` with 115442 bytes while the version that only uses `/` results in `bytes` of 86535 bytes. Therefore the results are quite different.

So How can I get the result without the added `\`s?

Comment: Why are you using `DataContractJsonSerializer` instead of `Json.NET`? Microsoft recommends the latter unless there is some really extenuating circumstance.

Comment: 2. there is nothing `incorrect` going on.  you simply want to show the json `without` the escape chars.  there are on-line formatters that do this but i'm not sure if that is what you're after (https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html)

Comment: According to [json.org/](https://json.org/) the `/` can be escaped as `\/`, therefore when you see `\/` in JSON, this is the same as the character `/`.

Comment: yes, theoretically they are the same however the results are quite different. (See my Edit)

Comment: after edit: the `json` is string with the JSON serialisation? Then of course there is different length *(more characters, bigger length)*. When you deserialise the value, the value should be the same. Unfortunately you did not write what JSON serialiser do you use *(not that I can help you, since I do not know details for any JSON serialisers)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard behavior of the `DataContractJsonSerializer` is to escape `/` characters in strings so that they become `\/` in JSON.  When the JSON is deserialized back to an object, the `\/` escape sequences will be turned back into `/` so no data is lost or corrupted.  (Try it and see.)  However it does result in a larger JSON size in bytes.  If this is really a concern for you, there are couple of things you can do to work around it:

**Approach 1**

Immediately after serializing, you could use `string.Replace()` to get rid of all backslashes which appear directly before slashes.  You can do this right in your `Serialize` method by changing this line:

```
returnVal = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

to this:

```
returnVal = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()).Replace("\\/", "/");
```

Because `/` has no special meaning in JSON, it's not actually necessary to escape them with `\`, although it is permissible to do so. (See page 5 of the [JSON specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf).)   `DataContractJsonSerializer` will still deserialize the JSON just fine even when slashes are not escaped. (Try it yourself and see.  I'd make a fiddle for this, but [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) doesn't support `DataContractJsonSerializer`).

**Approach 2** (recommended)

Switch to a better JSON serializer such as [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which does not escape the slashes in the first place.  You can simplify your code and replace your entire `Serialize` method with [`JsonConvert.SerializeObject()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm)

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MQKXSD